# i'm getting error while getting Finger print MD5 certification

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my path:C:\ANDROID\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore"C:\ANDROID\debugkey\debug.keystore"-storepass android -keypass android

keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, android is not a legal c
ommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to this 
space is needed.

```
keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\ANDROID\debugkey\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

You can also check the path to keystroke from eclipse

```
Goto window->preference->Android->Build
```

and see the path on right side.